# Invalid constant value on Border

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add a border to a container. However, when I put this code onto the `border` value, it trows me an `Invalid constant value` error.

My code goes like this:

```
border: new Border.all(
    color: Colors.grey,
    width: 0.5,
    style: BorderStyle.solid
),
```

I've double checked everything and I don't seem to find a misstype or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container doesn't have a border property, instead use a decoration

```
Container(
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.grey,
            width: 0.5,
            style: BorderStyle.solid
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I have my code ALMOST like that. However, I spotted a crutial difference. In my code, the BoxDecoration was marked as a 'const'. Removing the 'const' fixed the issue, thanks.

Comment: Glad I helped :)